# why is the node id missing from the comment:edit action?

Tags: comments, emails, actions, rules

When I setup a trigger on comment creation and edit that fires the action "send email" I have the folling tags available in the action editor that seem to be missing the nid on output:

```
[comment:edit-url]
[comment:url]
[comment:url:absolute]
```

This gives me the following output in emails

```
http://example.com/comment//edit
http://example.com/comment/#comment-
http://example.com/comment/#comment-
```

Is this a flaw in the D7 or and I not doing it right?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Denford: You are right in saying that comments do have ids. They are just called cids and not nids :-)

What is the trigger that you are firing? My guess is that for a new comment posted, you are not seeing the 'cids' because they would be available only to the trigger 'after saving a new comment' and not the trigger 'when either saving a new comment or updating.. blah blah'.

Comment: Cheers Sumeet, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't believe comments are considered "nodes" in the traditional Drupal sense.

The terminology is in flux, but traditionally nodes refer to pieces of content.

I believe comments now fit into the scheme as an entity, as just about everything else in Drupal now does.

This ambiguity is sort of an issue now with the advent of the entity system.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for you thoughts. When I add in the (not nid?) id to the // part of the first url it works as I would expect, taking me to the a page with just the comment to be edited. So comments seem to have id's, actions just seems to not know about them though.